# Unpack without using * (asterisk)

Tags: python, functional-programming, argument-unpacking

If I want to keep things functional, and do not want to use `*` in the middle, then what is the equivalent substitute function?
for example,

```
import operator as op
print(op.eq(*map(str.upper, ['a', 'A'])))
```

how do I avoid using `*` here?

I created a function, like,

```
def unpack(args):
  return *args
```

but it gives syntax error, `print(*args)` works but `return` fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by creating a function named `apply`.

```
def apply(func, args):
    return func(*args)
```

```
apply(op.eq, map(str.upper, ['a', 'A']))
```

Comment: You [tomb](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#apply) raider :-D

Answer (score 2):

[`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can be used to apply a function of two arguments to an iterable cumulatively, which would work for your example case

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(op.eq, map(str.upper, ['a', 'A'])))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to check if all of the mapped elements are equal to each other.

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(op.eq, map(str.upper, ['a', 'A'])))
```

This isn't really a sensible thing to do, though. I say this because the `reduce` call above doesn't generalize to cases with more or fewer elements:

- If the input were empty it would fail with `TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value`.
- If it were given a one-item input list it would return a string rather than a boolean `True` or `False`.
- If it were given list with 3+ items it would end up comparing strings to booleans and would always result in `False`.

If your plan is to call `op.eq` with exactly two operands, no more and no less, then unpacking with `*` is appropriate. Even in a functional context.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `reduce` if there is some safe value you know will not occur. For example, if you know `None` will not be in your list, you can do

```
import functools
mylist = list(map(str.upper, ['a', 'A']))
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x if x == y else None, mylist)
print('all equal' if result != None else 'some differ')
```